# Netbeans 11.3 Synchronization not available on remote project

Tags: php, netbeans

Got a weird one here.  Running Netbeans 11.3 with PHP projects.  Setup a completely new project and added Remote Sync settings.  Worked initially and then just stopped.  I've removed the nbproject directory and re-created the project and still I don't have the Synchronize, Upload, Download options available.

However, if I'm in the same session and jump to a different project... no problem at all.

I can't for the life of me work out what is different but it's infuriating.  There are no warnings, errors or anything - the options just aren't available.  I've tried creating a second FTP connection in case that was the issue but that didn't work either.

Anyone else had this issue?  I've confirmed my FTP connection is working perfectly (Via the Test Connection on the Project Configuration window).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try removing the closing Netbeans, removing project files and also cleaning the cache, in Linux `rm -rf ~/.cache/netbeans/11.3/`.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to update this - Turns out I had accidentally clicked the "Open as Project" option on the directory.  As a result Netbeans had created another nbproject folder under the folder I was trying to sync.   Because I hadn't defined any remote connection for the new project I couldn't sync.   Was quite the mission to remove the new directory but got there in the end.